# Jest issue in Angular - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning zone.js

Tags: angular, jestjs, zone

Currently trying to execute Jest in Angular. Getting an unhandledpromise error from `zoneDelegate`. Cannot seem to resolve. Tried to update `zone.js` to version `11` but that seems to generate new issues.

I've tried adding `async` to the spec.ts but that does not seem to resolve the issue.

Below my current `spec.ts`

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ForOthersDashboardComponent } from './for-others-dashboard.component';

describe('ForOthersDashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: ForOthersDashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ForOthersDashboardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ForOthersDashboardComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ForOthersDashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And my `jest.config`

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');

module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src/'],
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec).+(ts)'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test.ts'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: ['html'],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage/my-app',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      isolatedModules: true,
      astTransformers: {
        before: [
          'jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer',
          'jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer',
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths || {}, {
    prefix: '<rootDir>/'
  })
};
```

[image: screenshot]

EDIT

The error only seems to occur in spec files which import a module I need. So for example the spec file below. It is trying to load something out of `node_modules` which cannot be found. I've tried other solutions by setting the modules path but that does not seem to resolve this issue.

```
import { RequiredModule } from 'required-module-lib';

describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RequiredModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        DashboardComponent
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents()
    .then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }));
```

Comment: Check all your imported components and services into test. Some `JSON.stringify` causes this error. Probably due to wrong mocking process or whatever connected to providing wrong value

Comment: Consider posting error message instead of an image, this will make the question searchable at least. This happens only with a specific module, doesn't it? The module should be specified then because it's very relevant. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . *I've tried other solutions by setting the modules path but that does not seem to resolve this issue* - what exactly?